# Two targets with different Bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, target

I have two targets with different Bundle identifiers

> com.mycompany.internal.myapp

AND

> com.mycompany.internal.myapp-app

When I build and install both the targets in an ipad the first target is installing perfectly and the second one throws a pop-up with "unable to Download the App". When I check the console it shows the error as:

> "the parent bundle has the same identifier as sub-bundle....".

Is there any way to install two targets on on same iPad?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of project structure?...I think it would be of help.